# NgModules : Using method of one component in another

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two modules, one a root module and another shared. Here is the shared module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SomeComponent } from "./somecomponent";
@NgModule({
    declarations: [SomeComponent],
    exports: [SomeComponent]
})
export class SomeModule {}
```

I import `SomeModule` in my Root module like so:

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { SomeModule } from somemodule/somemodule';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports:      [BrowserModule, SomeModule],
    bootstrap:    [AppComponent], 
})
export class AppModule {}
```

It works fine until that point. Now, i want to use a method that is part of `SomeComponent` inside my `app.component`. But the problem is that the shared module does not directly expose `SomeComponent`.

How will i call any methods from `SomeComponent` in `AppComponent` class? What will change if the method is `static`?

**EDIT** : Maybe i was not clear before. But `SomeComponent` is a directive which i have no problem using in the template of `AppComponent` but it also has a static method that i need to call in the class of `AppComponent` and since i am importing it in Root module, it should be availble inside the AppComponent. I want something like this in AppComponent

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<some-component (someEvent)="handle($event)"></some-component>`
})
export class AppComponent {

  _constructor(){}

  handle(event){

   SomeComponent.someStaticMethod();

  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure about it, but I think the point of separating the components/modules is to... separate them. If you need a certain functionality to be available from multiple places in code, you need a service and inject it in a component/module.

Comment: what' the error you are getting ?

Comment: @candidJ I added some details.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** : Ok, for what you want to achieve, angular2 provides what they call ViewChild.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { SomeComponent } from './some.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<some-component (someEvent)="handle($event)"></some-component>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild(SomeComponent) private someComponent:SomeComponent;

    constructor () {}

    handle(event) {

        this.someComponent.someStaticMethod();
    }
}
```

I also added a Plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/8aGi4GNWUAKdf01ZPplB?p=preview


**INITIAL REPLY**

I am not sure if you indeed refer to components, or by components you mean classes in general.

In the first case, regarding parent and child component interactions in Angular2 (regardless of which module a component belongs to..), the way to invoke methods of the child component is by using a **#spy**:

```
<parent-component>
    <child-component #child></child-component>        
    <button (click)="child.someMethod()">Call method of child</button>
</parent-component>
```

In the second case, where you want the public methods of a class (regardless of what module this class belongs to) to be accessed by other classes (ex. a service accessed by components), you need to somehow create or pass an instance of this class(ex. service) to these other classes(ex. components). A way to achieve this in angular, is by using the @Injectable() decorator, and pass this class (service) to the constructor of each component that requires access to that service. Otherwise, just create a new instance of your class (`let a = new MyClass();`) and directly call its **public** method ( `a.somePublicMethod();` ).

ps. also note, that except from classes, components, services etc, in ES6 you can also export a plain function

```
export function myFunction(a: any, b: any) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: you are correct to point out the two methods but i don't think it address the current problem he's facing

Comment: i might have not understood exactly what the problem is :) But i don't have enough points yet to be able to comment in other's posts, so i could not ask for details!

Comment: Sorry but this does not work for. Please see the edits in my post for details.

Comment: @mpilliador Again, it's a valid solution but does not apply here as `SomeComponent` is a part of a module. It is not exposed directly.

Comment: @R.Hussain I might be missing something, but i don't get why this is a problem. I am using ng2-boostrap (just to provide a working example) in a project. For everything belonging to ng2-bootstrap, i am using a dedicated module. Then i import this module in other modules of my application, and i can directly use public method of ng2-boostrap components in the way that i described (using a @ViewChild). Have you actually tried it and it didn't work? I also added a plunker for your example to check how it's done.